# Gulp or node modules / npm error

Tags: angularjs, npm, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-uglify

I have troubles with gulp, I have run npm install command to install npm, then i run gulp, after that i am getting following error, i have tried a lot but not get any solution.

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
at createError (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\node_modules\gulp-uglify\lib\create-error.js:6:14)
at apply (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\node_modules\lodash\_apply.js:16:25)
at wrapper (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\node_modules\lodash\_createCurry.js:41:12)
at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\node_modules\gulp-uglify\lib\minify.js:54:15
at DestroyableTransform._transform (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\node_modules\gulp-uglify\composer.js:10:23)
at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:182:10)
at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:170:83)
at doWrite (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:406:64)
at writeOrBuffer (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:395:5)
at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:322:11)
```

package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "latest",
    "gulp-help": "latest",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "latest",
    "gulp-notify": "latest",
    "gulp-rename": "latest",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "latest",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-watch": "latest",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
    "lodash": "^4.14.0",
    "moment": "latest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: check if you have gulp-ugly as a dependency in package.json file. if not try npm install --save-dev gulp-uglify

Comment: Could you give some info about how you are using the task?

Comment: @HastaTamang I have already gulp-uglify, but as per your suggestion I run your giving command. I have updated above my package.json file.

Comment: Can you post your gulp.js file. Also the error is not clear try to log the error, using gulp-utll. var gutil = require('gulp-util');  then add this after uglify    .on('error', function (err) { gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('[Error]'), err.toString()); })